# PJAX/DJAX- rerun scripts after pjax load

Tags: javascript, requirejs, pjax

I'm using RequireJS to structure my JS and [DJAX](https://github.com/beezee/djax) (basically PJAX) as a way to dynamically load content without a full page reload.

The issue I have is that after DJAX has finished loading the content I need to rerun my scripts (e.g. a script that adds multiple images into a carousel) so that the new page renders correctly. I thought the best way to do this would be to simply rerun the function I'm running on `$(document).ready();` but I'm getting this output in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'djaxLoad' of undefined
```

which is referring to this line in **load-posts.js**

```
bootstrap.init();
```

I'm guessing I'm writing something incorrectly.

Here is **bootstrap.js** which is my main file which fires on document.ready and initialises all my modules

```
require(['base/responsive', 'base/main-menu', 'base/social-share', 'base/randomise-colours', 'base/infinite-scroll', 'base/load-posts', 'base/image-fade', 'base/carousel', 'base/misc'],
    function(responsive, main_menu, social_share, randomise_colours, infinite_scroll, load_posts, image_fade, carousel, misc) {

            var $ = jQuery;

            function djaxLoad() {
                //If page has JS (detected with Modernizr) then hide content until the
                //doc is ready to avoid flash of unstyled content
                $('#djax-container').css('display', 'block');

                main_menu.init();
                social_share.init();
                randomise_colours.init();
                load_posts.init();
                image_fade.init();
                infinite_scroll.init();
                carousel.init();
                misc.init();

                responsive.init();
            }

            $(document).ready(djaxLoad);
    }
);
```

And this is **load-posts.js** which handles DJAX for me. DJAX works, I just need to get the scripts to fire again.

```
define(['djax', 'base/bootstrap'], function(djax, bootstrap) {

    var $ = jQuery,
        $body = $('body');

    return {

        init: function() {
            if($body.length >= 1) {
                this.setUp();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        setUp: function() {
            this.pjaxLinks();
        },

        pjaxLinks: function() {
            //Initialise DJAX, but stop it from running on pagination links (URL is /page...)
            $('body').djax('.updateable', ['page']);

            //When clicking a djax link
            $(window).bind('djaxClick', $.proxy(function() {
                this.addLoader();
            },this));

            //When the new content has loaded in
            $(window).bind('djaxLoad', $.proxy(function() {
                this.removeLoader();
            },this));
        },

        addLoader: function() {
            $body.addClass('loader-visible');
        },

        removeLoader: function() {
            $body.removeClass('menu-visible');
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
            function removeLoaderDelay() {
                $body.removeClass('loader-visible');
                bootstrap.djaxLoad();
            }
            setTimeout(removeLoaderDelay, 1000);
        }

    };

});
```

The **djaxClick** function runs on a link click, and the **djaxLoad** function runs after the content has been loaded in. I'm adding a loader overlay to the page, then removing it after the content has loaded in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late but for future reference: In the documentation at https://github.com/beezee/djax you'll find the djaxLoad-event. This is specifically made for your usecase. You can use it as follows:

```
$(window).bind('djaxLoad', function(e, data) {
    // your scripts to run on ajax-calls
});
```

The site further explains: "the data object passed with the event contains the requested url, the page title for the requested page, and the contents of the requested page as a string".

```
$(window).bind('djaxLoad', function(e, data) {
    var responseObj = $('<div>'+data.response+'</div>');
    //do stuff here
});
```